# If I'm only supporting iPhone 4+ do I still need standard resolution assets

Tags: iphone, ios, assets, retina-display, artwork

My application will be iOS5+ and support only iPhone 4+ so the only screens it needs to work on will be retina displays.

Do I still need to use two sets of artwork or can I stick with just @2x artwork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your App is only for iPhone 4 and above, you can use only @2x resources. But take into account that iPad and iPad 2 are iOS 5 compatible and don't use @2x images.

Comment: I'm only targeting iPhone 4+. Do I need to support the iPad? Is in the submission guidelines?

Comment: Nop, it's not needed. But if you are planning to create an universal application (iPhone/iPad) you have to use both (1x and 2x scale resources) because iPad is iOS 5 compatible.